# Installing a new ca certificate for Perl 5.14.2 LWP on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: perl, ssl, ubuntu-12.04, lwp

I am getting the following error trying to connect to a specific https website using LWP:

```
LWP::Protocol::https::Socket: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown errorerror:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 51.
```

I tried with wget and got:

```
ERROR: cannot verify [domain]'s certificate, issued by `/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority/serialNumber=********':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
```

I googled around and discovered that I probably had to install the godaddy root ca cert. I figured out how to do that (download certificates, put in /usr/share/ca-certificates and run update-ca-certificates). I also learnt how to use openssl s_client in the process.

Now that the certificate is installed, wget works, but LWP still fails with the same error and so does openssl s_client:

```
# openssl s_client -connect [domain]:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 O = [domain], OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = [domain]
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 O = [domain], OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = [domain]
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 O = [domain], OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = [domain]
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
```

I have no idea where to go next to get this working. Any suggestions?

---

**EDIT:**  **SOLVED** Here is a simple script that describes what worked after mikew's suggestion:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::UserAgent;
$URL="[domain]";
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { SSL_ca_path=>'/etc/ssl/certs'});
my $response = $ua->get($URL);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a more specific answer, we'd need to know how you are instantiating your LWP object.

But what you probably need to know about is the `SSL_ca_file` and `SSL_ca_path` options for `ssl_opts` in the LWP constructor. Without one of these set, it assumes the Mozilla_CA is the CA to to use to verify websites.

See [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/module/GAAS/LWP-Protocol-https-6.04/lib/LWP/Protocol/https.pm)
And [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent#CONSTRUCTOR-METHODS), `ssl_opts` constructor option.

If you are using something like lwp-download and not actually instantiating the LWP::UserAgent object yourself, then you need to set the `PERL_LWP_SSL_CA_FILE` environment variable to point to your certificate authority or set `PERL_LWP_SSL_CA_PATH` to your CA path. You can just set these instead of passing in to `ssl_opts` as well.

If you aren't particularly worried about doing all this verification and like to live dangerously, you can set `verify_hostname => 0` for `ssl_opts` or set `PERL_LWP_VERIFY_HOSTNAME` environment variable to 0.

And as noted in the documentation, LWP 5.837 and earlier had `verify_hostname` off by default, whereas later versions default to it being on

Comment: Good to hear! Edited answer to clarify that only one of SSL_ca_file or SSL_ca_path is needed.